# Text-align and div not centered

Tags: css, html

I have a div that I want to be align in the center, horizontally speaking. Note that the `button` inside, can be align at the center... Sadly I can't make the same for the wrapper

[Here's is the live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dS9Bc/2/)

**HTML** markup:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="grayContainer">
        <div class="editor-label">
            name:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            james
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            last name:
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            bond
        </div>
        <div class="alignCenter">
            <input type="submit" value="press me" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** markup:

```
.grayContainer {
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
    width: 450px;
    background-color: #E7E7E7;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 2px #CCCCCC;
    position:relative;
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}

.grayContainer label
{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #656565;
    /*font-size: 12px;*/
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white;
    padding: 8px 13px 10px 0;
}

.grayContainer .alignCenter
{
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.alignCenter
{
    text-align: center;
}

.wrap
{
     margin: 0 auto;   
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have centered the wrapper, but as the width of it fills the available width you won't see that it's centered.

I think that you want to center the container inside the wrapper instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/dS9Bc/4/

Comment: I prefer not to modify the div `grayContainer`, is there another way to do this using the div `wrap`?

Comment: @LuisSánchez: Yes, you can make the `wrap` the same width as the `grayContainer`, then you can use `margin: 0 auto;` on it: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/dS9Bc/6/

Answer (score 3):

Set the left and right margins to `auto`.

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto
```

or even better

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dS9Bc/3/).

Comment: oh the margin has to be set on the wrapped div... `grayContainer`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to also set a width either `.wrap` will need one adding or set `margin: 0 auto;` to `.grayContainer`

Answer (score 0):

make margin right & left auto.. and just add this style to your css.. and it's not work on jsFiddle

```
.wrap{
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but, true, it doesn't work on jsFiddle, any idea of this?

Comment: It does work on jsFiddle, they use an iframe to display it so it works just like any other webpage. (http://jsfiddle.net/4Fm8D/) EDIT: The parent document have to be filling out the entire space, or it won't work. The code I posted wasn't qutie correct, still working.